# Playing an audio file on JButton press?

Tags: java, swing, audio, applet, javasound

I've looked on Google for a while, searching how to play audio files, and most of the sources I found were with using `java.applet.*`, but I am trying to look for a way I can put it inside my `actionPerformed()` method.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    if(event.getActionCommand().equals("Play")){
        //Short Audio File Playing Here
    }
}
```

Comment: please search first on stackoverflow regarding this... you will get many links... try them implementing and then ask if you have any difficulties...

Comment: also the applet code will come inside actioncommand method...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [JavaSound info. page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) for the "Playing a Clip" section.

Comment: Thanks for the reference!  Looking over it now.

Comment: I've looked over the source you've given, and works great first time! But when I want to press another button, it doesn't play.  I think it's because the clip may be already open.  I've tried `clip.close()`, then `clip.open()` right after, but for some reason still doesn't work?  Any suggestions?

Comment: 1) Ask a new question.  2) Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Hot-link to sounds (like the example on the JavaSound page).  There are some more samples available from [my site](http://pscode.org/media/#sound).

Answer (score 2):

You may learn and use `javax.sound` API. Have a look at tutorial -  [Playing Back Audio](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/playing.html).

Comment: Great reference, I'll look over it!

Comment: The issue may just be about needing to reset the position back to the start of the Clip. The above tutorial covers this. Managing the instance you create may be a little tricky given the implied multithreading, though. Clips don't multithread AFAIK.