# How to play multiple Clip instances?

Tags: java, audio, javasound, clip

I've looked over [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) reference on Java sound, and made a clip play.

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.chiptape.com/chiptape/sounds/medium/Taito_Carousel.wav");
AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

clip.open(ais);
clip.loop(0); //This lets the clip play fully before closing immediately
```

When I play this once, it works just fine, but when I want to play the same clip again with `clip.open(ais)`, it doesn't play.  Any ideas?

Comment: Was there some part of [2) Post an SSCCE.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8997483/418556) that you are having trouble understanding?  1 out of 2 ain't bad, it's woeful (IMO).  Post an ***SSCCE*** and I will look at the problem more closely.  BTW - if you can recreate this from the command line (no button) it indicates it has nothing to do with either buttons or GUIs.  If so, it does not make much sense to mention buttons at all, let alone in the title of the post.  I think "How to play multiple Clip instances?" would be a much better title for the post.  Edit it if you agree.

Comment: BTW - [tag:javasound] is a good tag to add for this type of question.  I was hoping you might have guessed that from the link I provided to the [JavaSound info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) that I added in your *last* question.

Answer (score 0):

javax.sound.sampled.Clip is not the easiest.

But this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/playing.html) is a good start:

> When you're ready to start playback, simply invoke the start method. To stop or pause the clip, invoke the stop method, and to resume playback, invoke start again. The clip remembers the media position where it stopped playback, so there's no need for explicit pause and resume methods. If you don't want it to resume where it left off, you can "rewind" the clip to the beginning (or to any other position, for that matter) using the frame- or microsecond-positioning methods mentioned above.

As Andrew says, if you post an example of the code, that would help folks to answer questions. But I'm guessing you are also just needing more background info, so that is why I'm giving the above links--which everyone dealing with Java Sound should know about.

Good luck!